# Vue JS 3 - How to detect a @keyup on an Android device?

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, vuejs3, keyup

Usually on a computer keyboard at a VueJS 3 form using this code below I can either click the button to try (in this case) to login, or if the user prefers, he'll can proceed further by pressing the Enter key while still having focus on the input.
<inp

```
<input type="email" placeholder="email@example.com" />
<input type="password" @keyup.enter="login" placeholder="Your password" />

<button @click="login">Login</button>
```

A user is using this form on an Android phone with its keyboard, when focused on the email input it'll have a "Next" button to change to the password input.
The password input, being the last input on this form, instead of a "Next" button it'll have a "Go" (or in my case "Ir") as you can see in the screenshot, but for what I can see that "Go" key isn't the same as an Enter, thus the "keyup.enter" doesn't work.

[Screenshot of the key on the android keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZSTP.png)

My question is what's the equivalent key in VueJS 3 to that "Go" button.

Comment: I've tried your code on my android phone and it works just fine. I'm using a differnet keyboard called TypeWise and I tested on Chrome
What Browser do you use on Android an what keyboar. Please also try keydown and keypress events

Comment: Thank you very much!
This is the case where the example I made by hand to short explain the problem ended up being better than the original code.
I guess it's better to delete the question for being silly.